# A matrix pointer into sub-matrices in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have this matrix in C.

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
[9,10,11,12]
[13,14,15,16]
```

n x n, squared matrix.

I need to split this into four matrices:

```
[1,2]  [3,4] [9,10]  [11,12]
[5,6]  [7,8] [13,14] [15,16]
```

This will be represented inside an array like this:

`array[16] = [1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14,11,12,15,16]`

So far, I've done this:

```
int i,j;
int k = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
 for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
 {
  array[k] = matrix[i][j];
  k++;
 }
}

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
 for(j = 2; j < 4; j++)
 {
  array[k] = matrix[i][j];
  k++;
 }
}

for(i = 2; i < 4; i++ )
{
 for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
 {
  array[k] = matrix[i][j];
  k++;
 }
}

for(i=2;i<4;i++)
{
 for(j=2;j<4;j++)
 {
  array[k] = matrix[i][j];
  k++;
 }
}
```

As you can see, I've done 4 double for this, but, is there a dynamic way to do this? If I got a bigger matrix, like 8 x 8, how to do this? The split if bigger is the same as the example.

Comment: What do you mean the split is the same? Is it broken down into the same number of sub-matrices, or does the sub-matrix size stay the same?

Comment: Observe the regularity of the initial and end values of the loop variables `i` and `j`. What are the rules, given the size of the original matrix and the size of the sub-matrices? If you found them, it should be easy to have an outer loop, or two nested ones (instead of writing essentially the same double loop four -- or N! -- times), and computing the proper index start and end values. Programming is all about rules, and avoiding code duplication.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yes, if a matrix is 8x8, i´ll get 16 sub-matrices of 2x2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the pattern of the routines you are duplicating.

Basically you do the same thing, except that the start and end of **i** and **j** are different. So create a sub routine and pass them as parameter.

For example:

```
void get_sub_matrix(int input[][N], int start_row, int end_row, int start_col, int end_col, int[] result, int* result_offset)
{
   int offset = *result_offset;
   for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++)
   {
      for (int j = start_col; j < end_col; j++)
      {
         result[offset++] = input[i][j];
      }
   }
   *result_offset = offset;
}
```

Notice how the result-offset is increased inside the routine as more elements are added to the result array.

Now you can do:

```
int matrix[N][N];
int array[N*N];
int k = 0;

get_sub_matrix(matrix, 0, 2, 0, 2, array, &k);
get_sub_matrix(matrix, 0, 2, 2, 4, array, &k);
get_sub_matrix(matrix, 2, 4, 0, 2, array, &k);
get_sub_matrix(matrix, 2, 4, 2, 4, array, &k);
```

P.S: Haven't compiled it.

Comment: worked perfectly. Some tweaks and now is fully dynamic. Thanks!